# Satchmo product variation stock

Tags: django, satchmo

I am trying to set up a Satchmo site, but I am stuck at the product variation and the item in stock for the specific variation.

I am attaching the link ([THIS LINK](http://blueduck.vodka.com.tw/EMPOR/item.html)); please see the size section where I want to MARK the sold out variation of that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking actually. What is giving you trouble with Product Variation?

Regardless here is a [screencast](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/dec/23/satchmo-screencast/) by Lincoln Loop and the [offical tutorial](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/tutorial1.html) to help with Product Variation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Attribute options with boolean type (or other type if you need more complex configuration) for each size, and set up in the admin product form for each product if size is exists or not.

Here is [documentation in details with example](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/product-attributes.html).